# How to set startup parameters for Adaptation project in SAP Business Application Studio?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-business-application-studio

I have created an Adaptation project in Business Application Studio for a Standard Fiori app. I need to run it with a couple of initial parameters and their detail values. I am unable to add a Run Configuration for this Adaptation project. Is there a way to set startup parameters for an Adaptation project in BAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently SAP Fiori applications that require a mandatory start up parameter are not supported as an Adaptation project as per guidelines. Please find below prerequisites for creating an Adaptation project in BAS:

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP%20Business%20Application%20Studio/584e0bcbfd4a4aff91c815cefa0bce2d/9d2028f106d44424a0f4637541b6e25f.html